# IDEA can't find some package in hadoop source code

Tags: hadoop

I want to analyze Hadoop's source code. I download the source code file and import it into IDEA. But IDEA tell me it can't find package `org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf`.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried cloning the Hadoop repo from Github?

Comment: OK, I will try it.

Comment: The same result, I think maybe somewhere needs to be set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First, you should install Protocol Buffers 2.5.0.
2. Execute the command: `cd hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/proto/`
3. Execute the command: `protoc --java_out=../java *.proto`

Then It will generate automatically a protobuf folder in ipc and IDEA becomes no error.